# Should useEffect be the preferred hook for large data handling?

Tags: reactjs, performance, react-hooks

I'm trying to overcome rendering delays and general "took too long" violation errors in the console.

For example, I have an `onClick` that calls `setShowModal(true)`. When `showModal === true` it renders a component that processes a lengthy object. This results in `onClick` causing a `Violation] 'click' handler took 1000ms` console warning and significant latency in the user's ability to interact with the app while this component prepares to render.

To get around this, I implemented the following:

```
function SlowComponent(props.lengthyObject) {
    const [initialRenderingComplete, setRenderingComplete] = useState(false);
    const [isProcessing, setIsProcessing] = useState(true)
    const [slowProcessedObject, setSlowProcessedObject] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        if(initialRenderingComplete) {
             setSlowProcessedObject(
                 processData(props.lengthObject)
             )
    }, [initialRenderComplete])

    return isProcessing 
        ? 'This will render pretty quickly' 
        : <div>
             This will take up to 1 second to become available and the browser will complain if I don't render something while the data is processing
             <button onClick={() => triggerAnotherSlowProcess()}>Update lengthy object</button>
        </div>;
}
```

In short, is this how useEffect is intended to be used or should I be taking another hook or strategy into consideration? Are there any risks of memory leaks with this setup?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think the [tag:hook] tag refers to [React hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)...

Comment: If possible you can try to optimize the processing of object because operations shouldn't take a second to complete. Lead to a bad user experience

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri - the problem is that I'm doing client-side filtering and mapping to generate an updated list. I'm not sure of a method to optimize this feature.